# Append Multiple options to Select

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm trying to send multiple `file.getPath()` to make options in a select (in this case 4)

But Instead I'm getting everything in one line: http://prntscr.com/hjwtsd

What's the problem?

JAVA

```
List<GitlabRepositoryTree> files = GitLab.getBranchFiles(project,branch);

for (GitlabRepositoryTree file : files) {
    response.getWriter().write(file.getPath());
}
```

HTML

```
<select id="file" class="form-control" name="file">                                                  
<%-- JQUERY --%>
</select>
```

JQUERY

```
success: function (file) {
            $('#file').empty();             
            $('#file').append($("<option/>", {
                value: file,
                text: file
            }));
      }
```

Comment: in java code, you need to either use `writeLine`(not sure if it's available on the writer) or add new line character at the end: `"\n"`

Comment: You are outputting a series of strings from your Java code, and writing a single time inside a single `<option>` in your javascript. How did you expect to obtain more than one `<option>`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i tried use `$.each` but didn't work. What do I need to use?

Comment: @JohnnyAW none of them worked.

Comment: Various options, the easiest of which is probably to output a json file from your java code and expect it in your javascript. Or, if there are no spaces inside the path names you could cycle through `file.split(' ')`. But to expect jquery to automatically understand how to split that stream of unstructured text is just wishful thinking.

Comment: @TiagoSilva becuase it's only a part of the problem

Comment: @TiagoSilva like Federico suggested, you should send json array from your java code